# What does variable |= 0; do?

Tags: javascript

What does

```
radius |= 0;
```

do?

Found in these blur functions here: http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlur.js

Comment: Isn't thatsomething that you could have easily found out by trying and looking at the result?

Comment: Then I would have had to try out every possible value, still not knowing what the intention of this was.

Comment: No, you would have tried out three or four values and then you would have started to notice a certain pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converts `radius` to integral value, since `|` is a bit-operator (which force a 32-bit integer value).

```
radius |= 0
```

would be equivalent to

```
radius = (castToInt32(radius > 0 ? Math.floor(radius) : Math.ceil(radius))) | 0
```

if such a function as `castToInt32()` existed. `| 0` is an idiomatic JavaScript way to do the same thing. The operation itself is a no-op, since OR-ing each bit with `0` will return the same bit (`1 | 0 == 1`, `0 | 0 == 0`), the benefit is the casting of the value.

Comment: Is this the most performant way to do it?

Comment: [Yes](http://jsperf.com/cast-to-int32), or at least one of. On my computer, at least. (I believe these all do the same thing, but... I could have made a mistake.) Notice that the mathy way to do it is orders of magnitude slower, while all bit-manipulation ways are more or less the same.